# Very confused about transformers with central tap, rectifier and output usage

Tags: power-supply, transformer

Perhaps a dumb question but here it is. Let's say we have a step down transformer with a balanced central tap and three output wires: A - CT - B. Measuring the voltage before rectification shows 34 VAC between A and B, 17 VAC between A and CT, and B and CT. So, is this a 17-0-17 transformer?

Now suppose we rectify this, so we get that 34 VAC * 1.414 = 48 VDC at rectifier end, or 16 VDC between rectifier's + (or -) and CT. An example circuit requires +16V, -16V and 0V but this is exactly what confuses me. The circuit may be using positive output from rectifier to get + 16VDC, negative output from rectifier to get -16 VDC and that's possible because it also uses 0V or CT. This means the circuit works as a whole, with 34 VDC? Also, which is "ground" now? 0V or -16 VDC?

Comment: it is up to you to pick a ground reference point

Comment: how do you get 16 Vdc?

Comment: @jsotola I got 16 VDC when measuring either positive or negative from rectifier, and CT

Comment: Did you forget the smoothing capacitor?

Comment: I rolled back your question, because you added new issues that were not in the question at the time I answered.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, 3300uF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a 17 - 0 - 17 transformer.

Here are the various configurations for deriving different DC output voltages.

1. Using the transformer centre tap, two rectifier diodes and a filter capacitor.

[image]

The full-wave rectified DC output = √2 * 17 = 24 V

2. Using a full wave bridge rectifier (without using the transformer centre tap) and a filter capacitor.

[image]

The full-wave rectified DC output = √2 * 34 = 48 V

3. Using the transformer centre tap, a full-wave bridge rectifier and two filter capacitors.

[image]

The full-wave rectified DC outputs are + 24 V, +48 V and + / - 24 V.

Answer (score 0):

> So this is a 17-0-17 transformer?

yes

> who is "ground" now?

By convention "ground" is 0V. Any node in a circuit could be called ground, but once that node has been named "ground", it is by that very naming, at 0V.

Now, like with all generalizations, there "issues" to consider that make a categorical statement seem less categorical. In a schematic, we treat connecting wires as ideal. Thus, every point that is connected to a ground symbol in a schematic is (usually) treated as being at the same potential. In fact, however, real wires, real ground planes, the real earth, etc. all have non-zero impedances. So two points in a real circuit which are shown as connected to ground in a schematic may actually have different potentials. This gives rise to speaking of things like "ground bounce" and other phenomena that appear to conflict with my sweeping statement that ground == 0V. But, those special cases aside, when we speak of a node as ground, we are, by naming that node "ground", assigning it a potential of 0V.

---

Just an FYI to the OP. To find a *peak* voltage of a sine wave from the *rms* value, one multiplies by 1.414 as you did.

However, when one *measures* rectified AC voltage with a multimeter, the measurement might be peak, rms, or what I usually see is *average*. A multimeter set to AC volts will generally give an rms value *for a sine wave* input, but only for a sine wave. What a multimeter set to DC volts will give when supplied a rectified sine wave really depends upon the meter.

Comment: So when designing the PCB for an audio amplifier, I should use the 0V side to have the most massive amount of copper in the board?

Comment: Typically one layer of copper in a board is chosen to be largely a "ground plane". A ground plane is useful for controlling electrical noise. However, there may be other traces/connections that are required to carry much more current. Large current paths also require lots of copper. In some cases, it might be better to have a supply rail have the most massive amount of copper on a board, even though that supply rail is not called "ground".

Comment: @AramAlvarez it is quite common to put grounded copper in all the unused space in the board where it makes sense; if the board has multiple layers you can make an entire layer be ground. It's ultimately your decision, though, not mine.